# Как лучше реализовать переключения radiobutton на Javascript?

Tags: javascript, инспекция-кода

Всем привет, есть такой код:

```js
var label = document.querySelectorAll('.item-inner label[data-target]'),
  labelInner = document.querySelectorAll('.form-two label[data-target]'),
  itemDiv = document.querySelectorAll('.box-style'),
  itemDivInner = document.querySelectorAll('.box');

label.forEach(function(checked) {
 checked.addEventListener('click', function(e) {

 itemDiv.forEach(function(item){
  item.classList.remove('active');
 });

 var targetDiv = document.querySelector(this.getAttribute('data-target'));

 targetDiv.classList.add('active');

 });
});

labelInner.forEach(function(checked) {
 checked.addEventListener('click', function(e) {

 itemDivInner.forEach(function(item){
  item.classList.remove('active');
 });

 var targetDiv = document.querySelector(this.getAttribute('data-target'));

 targetDiv.classList.add('active');

 });
});
```

```css
@charset "UTF-8";
/* ---------------------------------------------
    Assets
--------------------------------------------- */
/* ---------------------------------------------
    Colors
--------------------------------------------- */
/* ---------------------------------------------
    Fonts
--------------------------------------------- */
/* ---------------------------------------------
    Stylings
--------------------------------------------- */
html, body {
    height: 100%;
}

body {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    width: 100%;
    /*display: -webkit-box;*/
    /*display: -moz-box;*/
    /*display: box;*/
    /*display: -webkit-flex;*/
    /*display: -moz-flex;*/
    /*display: -ms-flexbox;*/
    /*display: flex;*/
    /*-webkit-box-pack: center;*/
    /*-moz-box-pack: center;*/
    /*box-pack: center;*/
    /*-webkit-justify-content: center;*/
    /*-moz-justify-content: center;*/
    /*-ms-justify-content: center;*/
    /*-o-justify-content: center;*/
    /*justify-content: center;*/
    /*-ms-flex-pack: center;*/
    /*-webkit-box-align: start;*/
    /*-moz-box-align: start;*/
    /*box-align: start;*/
    /*-webkit-align-items: flex-start;*/
    /*-moz-align-items: flex-start;*/
    /*-ms-align-items: flex-start;*/
    /*-o-align-items: flex-start;*/
    /*align-items: flex-start;*/
    /*-ms-flex-align: start;*/
    background-color: #CCCC33;
    font-family: "Roboto Condensed", sans-serif;

}

.body-wrap{
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: flex;
    -webkit-flex-direction: column;
    -ms-flex-direction: column;
    flex-direction: column;
    -webkit-flex-wrap: nowrap;
    -ms-flex-wrap: nowrap;
    flex-wrap: nowrap;
    -webkit-justify-content: center;
    -ms-flex-pack: center;
    justify-content: center;
    -webkit-align-content: stretch;
    -ms-flex-line-pack: stretch;
    align-content: stretch;
    -webkit-align-items: center;
    -ms-flex-align: center;
    align-items: center;
}
/*@media (min-height: 580px) {*/
    /*!*body {*!*/
        /*!*-webkit-box-align: center;*!*/
        /*!*-moz-box-align: center;*!*/
        /*!*box-align: center;*!*/
        /*!*-webkit-align-items: center;*!*/
        /*!*-moz-align-items: center;*!*/
        /*!*-ms-align-items: center;*!*/
        /*!*-o-align-items: center;*!*/
        /*!*align-items: center;*!*/
        /*!*-ms-flex-align: center;*!*/
    /*!*}*!*/
/*}*/

.container {
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 580px;
    padding-right: 20px;
    padding-left: 20px;

    -webkit-order: 0;
    -ms-flex-order: 0;
    order: 0;
    -webkit-flex: 0 1 auto;
    -ms-flex: 0 1 auto;
    flex: 0 1 auto;
    -webkit-align-self: auto;
    -ms-flex-item-align: auto;
    align-self: auto;
}

.invoice {
    background-color: #ffffff;
    border-radius: 10px;
    box-shadow: 0 14px 28px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1), 0 10px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.13);
    margin: 50px 0;
    padding: 50px 30px 30px;
}
.invoice header {
    margin-bottom: 30px;
}
.invoice header section {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    padding-top: 120px;
}
.invoice header section:nth-of-type(1) h1 {
    /* float: left; */
    text-align: center;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-weight: 600;
    letter-spacing: 2px;
    color: #344760;
    font-size: 25px;
    margin-top: 20px;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
}
.invoice header section:nth-of-type(1) span {
    float: right;
    color: #b7bcc3;
    font-size: 14px;
    margin-top: 10px;
    letter-spacing: 2px;
}
.invoice header section:nth-of-type(1) .logo img {
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    left: 0;
    top: -35px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    content: "";
    height: 140px;
}
.invoice header section:nth-of-type(2) {
    float: right;
}
.invoice header section:nth-of-type(2) span {
    font-size: 21px;
    color: #b7bcc3;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
}
.invoice header section:nth-of-type(2) span:before {
    content: "#";
}
.invoice main {
    border-left-width: 0px;
    border-right-width: 0px;
    padding-top: 0;
    padding-bottom: 0;
}
.invoice footer {
    text-align: right;
    margin-top: 30px;
}
.invoice footer button {
    display: inline-block;
    padding-right: 0;
    padding-left: 0;
    background: none;
    border: none;
    font-size: 19px;
    font-family: inherit;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    position: relative;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
    cursor: pointer;
    outline: none;
    color: #CCCC33;
}
.invoice footer button:focus {
    border: none;
    outline: none;
}
.invoice footer button:-moz-focus-inner {
    border: none;
    outline: none;
}
.invoice footer button:after {
    content: "";
    width: 0%;
    height: 4px;
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    bottom: -10px;
    background-color: inherit;
    -webkit-transition: width 0.2s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: width 0.2s ease-in-out;
    transition: width 0.2s ease-in-out;
}
.invoice footer button:hover:after {
    width: 100%;
}
.invoice footer button:after {
    background-color: #CCCC33;
}
.invoice footer button:disabled {
    color: #b7bcc3;
    cursor: not-allowed;
}
.invoice footer button:disabled:hover:after {
    display: none;
}
.invoice footer button:disabled:after {
    background-color: #b7bcc3;
}
.iframe {
    display: block;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
.inner h2 {
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-weight: 600;
    letter-spacing: 2px;
    color: #344760;
    font-size: 20px;
    text-align: center;
    margin: 0 0 22px 0;
}
.inner input[type=text] {
    border: none;
    padding-top: 5px;
    padding-bottom: 5px;
    font-size: 16px;
    line-height: 24px;
    outline: none;
    color: #344760;
    width: 100%;
    box-shadow: 0 1px 0 0 #b7bcc3;
    transition: border-color .3s, box-shadow .3s;
}
.inner input[type=text]:focus {
    border: none;
    outline: none;
    box-shadow: 0 1px 0 0 #CCCC33;
}
.inner input[type=text]::-moz-focus-inner {
    border: none;
    outline: none;
    border-color: #CCCC33;
}
.inner textarea {
    width: 100%;
    text-align: left;
    resize: none;
    margin-top: 20px;
    font-size: 16px;
    border: none;
    outline: none;
    color: #344760;
    box-shadow: 0 1px 0 0 #b7bcc3;
    transition: border-color .3s, box-shadow .3s;
    padding: 10px 10px 20px 5px;
    min-height: 130px;
}
.inner textarea:focus {
    border: none;
    outline: none;
    box-shadow: 0 1px 0 0 #CCCC33;
}
.item {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    width: 50%;
    vertical-align: top;
    padding-right: 10px;
    display: inline-block;
    margin-right: -4px;
    text-align: center;
}
.form-item {
    margin-bottom: 20px;
}
.form-item .rub {
    vertical-align: bottom;
}
.form-item label {
    display: inline-block;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    font-weight: 600;
    color: #344760;
}
.rub {
    font-size: 17px;
    color: #344760;
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
.input-sum {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
    height: 56px;
    width: 110px;
}
.item label {
    display: inline-block;
    cursor: pointer;
    position: relative;
    padding-left: 25px;
    text-align: left;
}
.item label:before {
    content: "";
    display: inline-block;
    width: 16px;
    height: 16px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    margin-right: 10px;
    border: 1px solid #CCCC33;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 1px;
}
.item input[type=radio] {
    display: none;
}
.item input[type=radio]:checked + label:after {
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #CCCC33;
    height: 10px;
    width: 10px;
    content: "";
    display: inline-block;
    left: 4px;
    top: 4px;
    border-radius: 50%;
}
.item input[type=radio]:checked + label > span {
    border-bottom: 1px solid green;
}
.box-style {
    margin-top: 30px;
    display: none;
}
.box {
    margin-top: 30px;
    display: none;
}
.box-style p {
    line-height: 21px;
}
.box-style .col-item {
    width: 50%;
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 0 5px;
    margin-right: -4px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
.active {
    display: block;
}
```

```html
<body>

<div class="body-wrap">
 <div class="container">
  <form class="invoice">
 <header>
  <section>
    <h1 class="invoice-title">Выберите тип платежа</h1>
  </section>
 </header>
 <main>
  <section class="inner">
   <div class="item-inner">
    <div class="item">
     <input id="sub1" name="form" type="radio" value="">
     <label for="sub1" data-target=".form-one"><span>Оплата услуг по договору</span></label>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
     <input id="sub2" name="form" type="radio">
     <label for="sub2" data-target=".form-two"><span>Оплата Госпошлины</span></label>
    </div>
   </div>
   <div class="box-style form-one">
    <div class="form-item">
     <label for="sub3">ФИО плательщика</label>
     <input type="text" id="sub3" placeholder="Иванов Иван Иванович">
    </div>
    <div class="form-item">
     <span class="input-sum">
      <label for="sub4">Сумма</label>
      <input type="text" id="sub4">
     </span>
     <span class="rub">&#8381;</span>
    </div>
   </div>
   <div class="box-style form-two">
    <h2>выберите способ оплаты</h2>
    <div class="item">
     <input id="sub5" name="form1" type="radio" value="">
     <label for="sub5" data-target=".form-three"><span>Сбербанк</span></label>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
     <input id="sub6" name="form1" type="radio">
     <label for="sub6" data-target=".form-four"><span>Онлайн Платеж</span></label>
    </div>
    <div class="box form-three">
     <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Porro eum tempora libero recusandae mollitia? Tenetur neque aperiam voluptates corrupti repellat qui veritatis, debitis eos nam eaque assumenda voluptate, iusto corporis!</p>
    </div>
    <div class="box form-four">
     <h2>Title</h2>
          <p>Далеко-далеко за словесными горами в стране, гласных и согласных живут рыбные тексты. Первую злых живет повстречался предложения то своего по всей это, текста знаках всеми, раз путь щеке коварных. Даль, злых дороге мир.</p>
    </div>
   </div>
  </section>
 </main>

    <footer>
    <button type="submit" id="payment_button" disabled="">Оплатить</button>
    </footer>
  </form>
 </div>
</div>
```

Здесь все как бы нормально работает, но в js там не совсем все правильно реализовано. Если посмотрите js код, то тут я просто продублировал код для вложенных радиобатонах, тех которые появляются при клике на 'Оплата Госпошлины'. Я думаю что я не совсем правильно это тут реализовал, но как сделать по другому идей нет. Можете пожалуйста подсказать, как будет правильнее такое сделать ?

Comment: Объедините в одну функцию и вызывайте её при ForEach

Comment: @Yuri тут же у меня просто еще разные классы для div которые показываются при клике на radiobutton, то есть для первых один класс box-style по которому я через цикл прохожу и убираю класс active, и во вложенных radiobutton тоже в тех блоках есть класс box по которому я также прохожу и убираю активных класс. Как это мне реализовать в функции в одной можно ?

Comment: `function check(checked, class) {}` ?

Comment: В коде ошибка. `querySelectorAll` возвращает коллекцию а не массив, у неё нет матода forEach. Её Нужно преобразовать в массив.

Comment: @Yuri я понял вашу мысль, попробую сам сейчас это все реализовать, если не получится, то уж опять сюда напишу в комментарии.

Comment: @Lorax, давайте :)

Comment: @Yuri спасибо за помощь!

Answer (score 0):

Объедините всё в одну функцию:

```js
var label = document.querySelectorAll('.item-inner label[data-target]'),
    labelInner = document.querySelectorAll('.form-two label[data-target]'),
    itemDiv = document.querySelectorAll('.box-style'),
    itemDivInner = document.querySelectorAll('.box');

function check(e, className) {
  className.forEach(function(item){
    item.classList.remove('active');
  });
  var targetDiv = document.querySelector(e.getAttribute('data-target'));
  targetDiv.classList.add('active');
};

label.forEach(function(checked) {
  checked.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    check(this, itemDiv);
  });
});

labelInner.forEach(function(checked) {
  checked.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    check(this, itemDivInner);
  });
});
```

```css
@charset "UTF-8";

html, body {
  height: 100%;
}

body {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  width: 100%;
  font-family: "Roboto Condensed", sans-serif;
}

.body-wrap{
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: flex;
    -webkit-flex-direction: column;
    -ms-flex-direction: column;
    flex-direction: column;
    -webkit-flex-wrap: nowrap;
    -ms-flex-wrap: nowrap;
    flex-wrap: nowrap;
    -webkit-justify-content: center;
    -ms-flex-pack: center;
    justify-content: center;
    -webkit-align-content: stretch;
    -ms-flex-line-pack: stretch;
    align-content: stretch;
    -webkit-align-items: center;
    -ms-flex-align: center;
    align-items: center;
}
/*@media (min-height: 580px) {*/
    /*!*body {*!*/
        /*!*-webkit-box-align: center;*!*/
        /*!*-moz-box-align: center;*!*/
        /*!*box-align: center;*!*/
        /*!*-webkit-align-items: center;*!*/
        /*!*-moz-align-items: center;*!*/
        /*!*-ms-align-items: center;*!*/
        /*!*-o-align-items: center;*!*/
        /*!*align-items: center;*!*/
        /*!*-ms-flex-align: center;*!*/
    /*!*}*!*/
/*}*/

.container {
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 580px;
    padding-right: 20px;
    padding-left: 20px;

    -webkit-order: 0;
    -ms-flex-order: 0;
    order: 0;
    -webkit-flex: 0 1 auto;
    -ms-flex: 0 1 auto;
    flex: 0 1 auto;
    -webkit-align-self: auto;
    -ms-flex-item-align: auto;
    align-self: auto;
}

.invoice {
    background-color: #ffffff;
    border-radius: 10px;
    box-shadow: 0 14px 28px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1), 0 10px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.13);
    margin: 50px 0;
    padding: 50px 30px 30px;
}
.invoice header {
    margin-bottom: 30px;
}
.invoice header section {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    padding-top: 120px;
}
.invoice header section:nth-of-type(1) h1 {
    /* float: left; */
    text-align: center;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-weight: 600;
    letter-spacing: 2px;
    color: #344760;
    font-size: 25px;
    margin-top: 20px;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
}
.invoice header section:nth-of-type(1) span {
    float: right;
    color: #b7bcc3;
    font-size: 14px;
    margin-top: 10px;
    letter-spacing: 2px;
}
.invoice header section:nth-of-type(1) .logo img {
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    left: 0;
    top: -35px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    content: "";
    height: 140px;
}
.invoice header section:nth-of-type(2) {
    float: right;
}
.invoice header section:nth-of-type(2) span {
    font-size: 21px;
    color: #b7bcc3;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
}
.invoice header section:nth-of-type(2) span:before {
    content: "#";
}
.invoice main {
    border-left-width: 0px;
    border-right-width: 0px;
    padding-top: 0;
    padding-bottom: 0;
}
.invoice footer {
    text-align: right;
    margin-top: 30px;
}
.invoice footer button {
    display: inline-block;
    padding-right: 0;
    padding-left: 0;
    background: none;
    border: none;
    font-size: 19px;
    font-family: inherit;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    position: relative;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
    cursor: pointer;
    outline: none;
    color: #CCCC33;
}
.invoice footer button:focus {
    border: none;
    outline: none;
}
.invoice footer button:-moz-focus-inner {
    border: none;
    outline: none;
}
.invoice footer button:after {
    content: "";
    width: 0%;
    height: 4px;
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    bottom: -10px;
    background-color: inherit;
    -webkit-transition: width 0.2s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: width 0.2s ease-in-out;
    transition: width 0.2s ease-in-out;
}
.invoice footer button:hover:after {
    width: 100%;
}
.invoice footer button:after {
    background-color: #CCCC33;
}
.invoice footer button:disabled {
    color: #b7bcc3;
    cursor: not-allowed;
}
.invoice footer button:disabled:hover:after {
    display: none;
}
.invoice footer button:disabled:after {
    background-color: #b7bcc3;
}
.iframe {
    display: block;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
.inner h2 {
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-weight: 600;
    letter-spacing: 2px;
    color: #344760;
    font-size: 20px;
    text-align: center;
    margin: 0 0 22px 0;
}
.inner input[type=text] {
    border: none;
    padding-top: 5px;
    padding-bottom: 5px;
    font-size: 16px;
    line-height: 24px;
    outline: none;
    color: #344760;
    width: 100%;
    box-shadow: 0 1px 0 0 #b7bcc3;
    transition: border-color .3s, box-shadow .3s;
}
.inner input[type=text]:focus {
    border: none;
    outline: none;
    box-shadow: 0 1px 0 0 #CCCC33;
}
.inner input[type=text]::-moz-focus-inner {
    border: none;
    outline: none;
    border-color: #CCCC33;
}
.inner textarea {
    width: 100%;
    text-align: left;
    resize: none;
    margin-top: 20px;
    font-size: 16px;
    border: none;
    outline: none;
    color: #344760;
    box-shadow: 0 1px 0 0 #b7bcc3;
    transition: border-color .3s, box-shadow .3s;
    padding: 10px 10px 20px 5px;
    min-height: 130px;
}
.inner textarea:focus {
    border: none;
    outline: none;
    box-shadow: 0 1px 0 0 #CCCC33;
}
.item {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    width: 50%;
    vertical-align: top;
    padding-right: 10px;
    display: inline-block;
    margin-right: -4px;
    text-align: center;
}
.form-item {
    margin-bottom: 20px;
}
.form-item .rub {
    vertical-align: bottom;
}
.form-item label {
    display: inline-block;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    font-weight: 600;
    color: #344760;
}
.rub {
    font-size: 17px;
    color: #344760;
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
.input-sum {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
    height: 56px;
    width: 110px;
}
.item label {
    display: inline-block;
    cursor: pointer;
    position: relative;
    padding-left: 25px;
    text-align: left;
}
.item label:before {
    content: "";
    display: inline-block;
    width: 16px;
    height: 16px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    margin-right: 10px;
    border: 1px solid #CCCC33;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 1px;
}
.item input[type=radio] {
    display: none;
}
.item input[type=radio]:checked + label:after {
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #CCCC33;
    height: 10px;
    width: 10px;
    content: "";
    display: inline-block;
    left: 4px;
    top: 4px;
    border-radius: 50%;
}
.item input[type=radio]:checked + label > span {
    border-bottom: 1px solid green;
}
.box-style {
    margin-top: 30px;
    display: none;
}
.box {
    margin-top: 30px;
    display: none;
}
.box-style p {
    line-height: 21px;
}
.box-style .col-item {
    width: 50%;
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 0 5px;
    margin-right: -4px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
.active {
    display: block;
}
```

```html
<body>

<div class="body-wrap">
  <div class="container">
    <form class="invoice">
      <header>
        <section>
          <h1 class="invoice-title">Выберите тип платежа</h1>
        </section>
      </header>
      <main>
        <section class="inner">
          <div class="item-inner">
            <div class="item">
              <input id="sub1" name="form" type="radio" value="">
              <label for="sub1" data-target=".form-one"><span>Оплата услуг по договору</span></label>
            </div>
            <div class="item">
              <input id="sub2" name="form" type="radio">
              <label for="sub2" data-target=".form-two"><span>Оплата Госпошлины</span></label>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="box-style form-one">
            <div class="form-item">
              <label for="sub3">ФИО плательщика</label>
              <input type="text" id="sub3" placeholder="Иванов Иван Иванович">
            </div>
            <div class="form-item">
              <span class="input-sum">
                <label for="sub4">Сумма</label>
                <input type="text" id="sub4">
              </span>
              <span class="rub">&#8381;</span>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="box-style form-two">
            <h2>выберите способ оплаты</h2>
            <div class="item">
              <input id="sub5" name="form1" type="radio" value="">
              <label for="sub5" data-target=".form-three"><span>Сбербанк</span></label>
            </div>
            <div class="item">
              <input id="sub6" name="form1" type="radio">
              <label for="sub6" data-target=".form-four"><span>Онлайн Платеж</span></label>
            </div>
            <div class="box form-three">
              <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Porro eum tempora libero recusandae mollitia? Tenetur neque aperiam voluptates corrupti repellat qui veritatis, debitis eos nam eaque assumenda voluptate, iusto corporis!</p>
            </div>
            <div class="box form-four">
              <h2>Title</h2>
              <p>Далеко-далеко за словесными горами в стране, гласных и согласных живут рыбные тексты. Первую злых живет повстречался предложения то своего по всей это, текста знаках всеми, раз путь щеке коварных. Даль, злых дороге мир.</p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </section>
      </main>
      
      <footer>
        <button type="submit" id="payment_button" disabled="">Оплатить</button>
      </footer>
    </form>
  </div>
</div>
```